# How to modify values of checkboxes in database and how to show checkboxes after submit button

Tags: php, sql, forms, checkbox

Ok so, the first question would be 'How can I show the check boxes after clicking submit'.

I have a code that shows the username field and the checkboxes on the same page. I would like to check if the 'username' is in the database and then show the checkboxes with the options, and if they have already options checked show them to modify the record on the database.

My code is this. (form where it shows the form and i dont want to show the whole thing only the username field and then the checkboxes).

```
<form name="form1" action="test3.php" method="post">
        <table width="100%" >

    Please enter your Username: <input type = "Text" value ="" name = "username"><br />

    Please select the category that you want to receive on your moval.edu e-mail account.<br /><br />
    <b>Athletics:</b><br><br />
    <b>MENS</b><br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Football">Football<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Baseball">Baseball<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Mens Basketball">Basketball<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Mens Cheer">Cheer<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Mens Cross Country">Cross Country<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Mens Golf">Golf<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Mens Lacrosse">Lacrosse<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Mens Rodeo">Rodeo<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Mens Soccer">Soccer<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Mens Tennis">Tennis<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Mens Track">Track<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Mens Volleyball">Volleyball<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Mens Wrestling">Wrestling<br><br />

    <b>WOMENS</b><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Womens Basketball">Basketball<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Womens Cheer">Cheer<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Womens Cross Country">Cross Country<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Dance">Dance<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Womens Golf">Golf<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Womens Lacrosse">Lacrosse<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Womens Rodeo">Rodeo<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Womens Soccer">Soccer<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Softball">Softball<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Womens Tennis">Tennis<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Womens Track">Track<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Womens Volleyball">Volleyball<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Womens Wrestling">Wrestling<br><br />

    <b>STUDENT AFFAIRS ACIVITIES</b><br><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Student Affairs"> Sign me up for Student Affairs Activities<br /><br />

    <b>INTERNAIONAL CLUB ACTIVITIES</b><br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="International Club"> Sign me up for International Club Activities<br /><br />

    <b>HISTORICAL ACTIVITIES</b><br><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Historical Activities"> Sign me up for Hisorical Activities<br /><br />

    <b>CONTESTS</b><br><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Contests"> Sign me up for Contests<br /><br />

    <b>LIBRARY EVENTS</b><br><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Library Events"> Sign me up for Library Evens<br /><br />

    <b>VIKING EXCHANGE</b><br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="Viking Exchange"> Sign me up for Viking Exchange News<br /><br />


</table>





<input name="cmd_submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

And here the action.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['mode'])) {
$mode = implode(",", $_POST['mode']);   
} else {
$mode = "";
}
?>


<?php
$dbhost  = 'localhost';
$dbname  = 'db_name';
$dbuser  = 'username';
$dbpass  = 'pass'; 

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if($con == FALSE)
{
    echo 'Cannot connect to database' . mysql_error();
}
else
{
    echo 'Connected to database';
}

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
// Get values from form 
$username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);

$sql="INSERT INTO email(username, mode) VALUES('$username', '$mode')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You must understand the fact the `id` must be unique. Multiple elements must not be identified by same id.

Comment: Yes I have ID in my database. The thing is I want that ID (besides being unique) to show what they already have checked and if they want to uncheck something save it back. But how do I check that ID with the username assigned and the options checked? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `checked="checked"` to have a checkbox checked by default.

Comment: Please specify. Where do I put that. But that's not an answer for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the form open a while loop which selects the checkbox fields from the database which are already selected. And check the condition as shown below whether it is equal to the checkbox in the form. If so make it as selected. An example is shown below:

```
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT checkbox_fields FROM table_name");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($row))
    {



  <input type="checkbox" name="football" id="football" value="football" <?php echo ($row['checkbox_fields']==football ? 'checked' : '');?>>Footbal<br>

     <input type="checkbox" name="baseball" id="baseball" value="baseball" <?php echo ($row['checkbox_fields']==baseball ? 'checked' : '');?>>Baseball<br>
etc...

    }
```

Comment: The thing is that the checkboxes are not in the database, simply the value of the checkbox is shown in the database separated by commas. And creating a field in the database for each checkbox is too much.

Comment: you must compare the value of the check boxes in the database that is what I meant. it is not a good practice to store the values separated by commas. In order to make it checked you have to do what I posted earlier.